# PHP: Using Proper Indentation with Heredocs

Tags: php, formatting, coding-style, indentation

I just read thought php doucmentation for [heredocs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) but I did not see any way to intent the code properly.  Is this possible in php?

Right now I am doing this, but this is bad for readability.

```
<?php

        if(something){
            ...
            echo <<< END      
                    This is a test.  I am writing this
                    text out.  
END; 
        } # end of if statment
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
<?php

        if(something){
            ...
            echo <<< END      
                    This is a test.  I am writing this
                    text out.  
            END; 
        } # end of if statment
```

I know that bash has a method to do this (although I cannot remember what it is), so I was wondering if it was possible to do in php.  I don't think so but I thought I would ask.

Comment: It is now possible with PHP >= 7.3. There's a comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51165453/1119601 explaining it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a limitation of PHP to properly format Heredoc statements. It's a parser limitation. As the documentation states:

> It is very important to note that the
> line with the closing identifier must
> contain no other characters, except
> possibly a semicolon (;). That means
> especially that the identifier may not
> be indented, and there may not be any
> spaces or tabs before or after the
> semicolon. It's also important to
> realize that the first character
> before the closing identifier must be
> a newline as defined by the local
> operating system. This is \n on UNIX
> systems, including Mac OS X. The
> closing delimiter (possibly followed
> by a semicolon) must also be followed
> by a newline.
>
> If this rule is broken
> and the closing identifier is not
> "clean", it will not be considered a
> closing identifier, and PHP will
> continue looking for one. If a proper
> closing identifier is not found before
> the end of the current file, a parse
> error will result at the last line.

It's unknown if this is gonna be resolved in the future of PHP.

Comment: Yes, it was resolved in PHP 7.3. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51165453/1119601

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, that's not possible, you need to put closing heredoc identifier *without any spaces/tabs/indentation :(*