# php formatting string EOD

Tags: php

i got the code

```
$confirm = "if (!confirm('".Module::t("Approve") . "?')) return false;";

$js_approve =<<< EOD
function() {
    $confirm
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.post(url, function(response) {
        alert(response);
    });
    return false;
}
EOD;
```

is it possible to transform to code like this

```
    $js_approve =<<< EOD
    function() {
        "if (!confirm('".Module::t("Approve") . "?')) return false;";
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.post(url, function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });
        return false;
    }
    EOD;
```

any ideas?

Comment: You mean you want to indent it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HEREDOC interfering with code indentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305869/heredoc-interfering-with-code-indentation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart that you can't indent, you can't also write this line

```
"if (!confirm('".Module::t("Approve") . "?')) return false;";
```

inside the heredoc.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not. You may not use indenting for heredoc strings.

You should read the warning on this page:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 0):

To prevent PHP from parsing the text use [nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) syntax (since PHP 5.3.0)

Comment: i read it, but can't see how it can help me to run function. only variables

Answer (score 0):

From this bit in the PHP docs:

> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except possibly a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system. This is \n on UNIX systems, including Mac OS X. The closing delimiter (possibly followed by a semicolon) must also be followed by a newline.

It says that the identifier may not be indented. I like to keep my indentation clean, and you can carry on as you would normally, but the only thing you must pay attention to is that the closing `EOD;` has *no* other characters before it on that line (ie, it must have a preceding newline). Other than that, everything will work the way you expect it to.

Taking your code as an example:

```
    $js_approve =<<< EOD
    function() {
        "if (!confirm('".Module::t("Approve") . "?')) return false;";
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.post(url, function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });
        return false;
    }
EOD;
```

Would work fine

Comment: Ah my apologies. Speaking from experience, this kind of stuff works for me, although I've never tried it with objects. Maybe try replacing `".Module::t("Approve") . "` with `{Module::t("Approve")}`, although this is untested.