# I used heredoc syntax to cover my string. But It displays error. Below is my code:

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HEREDOC interfering with code indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305869/heredoc-interfering-with-code-indentation)

```
<?php
        $my_string = <<<TO
         Everything in this rather unnecessarily wordy
        ramble of prose will be incorporated into the 
        string that we are building up inevitably, 
        inexorably, character by character, line by line, 
        until we reach that blessed //final line which is this one.
        TO;
        echo $my_string;
    ?>
```

it's error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\wamp\www\ITP - Teaching\PHP\Chapter VIII - String\Heredoc Syntax\index.php on line 19
```

Answer (score 6):

The closing `TO` must not be indented.

Answer (score 2):

Heredoc end needs to be at the start of a row, try this:

```
<?php
        $my_string = <<<TO
         Everything in this rather unnecessarily wordy
        ramble of prose will be incorporated into the 
        string that we are building up inevitably, 
        inexorably, character by character, line by line, 
        until we reach that blessed //final line which is this one.
TO;
        echo $my_string;
    ?>
```