# image wont show using an id from database

Tags: php, html, sql, image

Hi i am trying to get an image to display when a result is picked from a data base this is my code below:

```
$box .= '<div style="margin-top:10px;height:120px;"id=\"Video\">
         <br/>
         <div style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#00000;width:400px;float:right;"id=\"Title\">'.$row['title'].'</div> 
         <div style="width:220px;height:150px;float:left;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;" id=\"VideoImage\">"

         <img class="partimg1"  src="classroom/images/'.$row['media_id'].'.jpg" /></div>  

<div style="height:50px;width:400px;float:right;padding:2px;margin-bottom:5px;" id=\"Blurb\">'.$row['blurb'].'</div>
<div style="height:21px;width:152px;margin-top:45px;margin-left:7px;background:url(images/bg_top_img2-09.jpg) repeat-x;color:#ffffff;padding-left:2px;float:left;border:1px solid #000000;position:relative;border-radius:15px;text-align:center;" id=\"Downloads\"> Download </div>
</div>';
```

the line with in the middle is where the image should be the `.$row['media_id'].` this will be a value from the database it will only be a number so for example 1 up to 50 and in the images folder the images are named 1 to 50 and they are all JPG is there something that i have missed because i have used this before and it worked.

all that displays on the screen is a broken image link like when the web page cannot find the image in the folder.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: in this case you do not need to have \ before double quotes. this is needed when your parent and child quotes are same. Also please double check the spaces before attributes like id etc.

Comment: Don't build the HTML like that, its prone to all kinds of errors, mostly quoting ones like here. Consider using [output buffers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) or [heredoc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581315/php-heredoc-string-rules) for building variables containing HTML.

Comment: @vlzvl I have no idea what any of that means the reason I am using html in this way is because it is duplicated with how many sets of results there are from the database and this is just the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You break the `src` link.

`src=\"classroom/images/'.$row['media_id'].'.jpg\"/>`

Answer (score 1):

As you use simple quote `'` for string delimiter, you don't need to escape double ones `"`

```
<img class=\"partimg1\"  src=\"classroom/images/"'.$row['media_id'].'".jpg\"/>
```

Should be

```
<img class="partimg1"  src="classroom/images/'.$row['media_id'].'.jpg" />
```

You also need to fix all your `id` attributes

Comment: the reason why I have the \ in front of " is because all of this html is within php and it will not work unless you put these in @MarioJohnathan

Comment: Yes, but you use `'` arround your string, so you don't need to escape `"`

Comment: ok @MarioJohnathan i have changed my code to why you have said and it still shows a broken link on the page any ideas ?

Comment: Are you sure images are in the specified folder? How is the URL which displays this page?

Comment: im doing this on a local server so my link is **http://thor/classroom/content.php** and inside classroom is the images folder called **images** and yes the pictures are within this folder

Comment: So try with `src="images/` instead of `src="classroom/images/`

Comment: it still displays the broken image link

Comment: And with `src="/thor/classroom/images/` ?

Comment: still the broken link

Comment: the original code that i used with this in is: `echo "<img class=\"partimg1\"  src=\"productimages/".$row['partnum'].".jpg\" onError=\"this.src='productimages/".$row['classid'].".jpg'\"/>";`

Comment: Are you sure your images have ".jpg" extension? Maybe they are ".jpeg"

Comment: I have figured it out it wasn't a problem with this section of the code it was the SQL query I hadn't referenced the media_id in the select statement